# Full crawl not picking up the properties from content type even though they are populated and being used

Tags: search, crawling, properties, managed-property

After running multiple full crawl the search service app still not picking up the metadata or properties from site column and content types. The columns are well populated with 500,000+ documents.

The old search broke so created a new search service application and re-crawl multiple times. Please suggest what else I should be checking or doing? Do I need to run some powershell command to add these properties (I shouldnt have to as SP should pick them up since they are pretty well populated).

Under stress and fire. Please suggest.

Added: There are variety of column types (managed-metadata, sp built-in column type). No custom fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the properties you want to retrieve in the Managed Properties section of the Service Application? Note that this is different from the 'Managed Metadata' Service Application (perhaps poor naming on MS' part). You'll also want to ensure that the Managed Properties you have are included in the index.

Comment: There are over 100 site columns that not are not showing up and adding them manually would out of question.

Comment: I'm afraid adding them is your only option if you want them to be crawlable. Luckily, there is some PowerShell you can write to automate the process. Give me a few minutes and I'll remind myself (I wrote script to do this recently).

Comment: My code's buried in an archive that I'm having problems accessing atm (VPN's playing up) - have a look at this instead, same thing pretty much: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/mattlally/archive/2011/12/20/create-sharepoint-2010-search-crawl-and-managed-properties-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thank you James. Let me give that a try. Also, if you could find your feel free to share them. Thanks

Comment: I'm not back in the office until Tuesday, but what I have is a simplified function that doesn't need an XML file, you just call the function multiple times, passing in the name of the required Managed and Crawled Properties each time.

Comment: Actually, SP crawled all the properties but did not map them. What a pia (pain in a ***). Can anyone suggest a way to map these crawl properties?

Comment: You gotta map them yourself once you've created a Managed Property. Luckily, there's a powershell command to do that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608017.aspx

Comment: Actually, the new search app is working. All I had to do is to create a new search site or I could just add new search web parts to old search site. Now I get the results. Lucky, good for me. I dont have to run ps to map crawl properties.